# Anaconda Installation stuck on Win x86 64 bit machine

Tags: installation, anaconda

I was trying to reinstall Anaconda on my Windows machine but have been running into a lot of issues. The installation gets stuck at extracting packages.

I have tried multiple time with available recommendations but to no avail. Prior to installation, I've always cleaned the entire path and directories but I end up on with the same issue. The installer gets stuck at various points at different install instances.

Another thing that I noticed is that although I am using a 64 bit installer, Task Manager lists it as 32 bit. I am attaching a few screenshots too.

Thank you for the help.

Current Scenario

[image]

Comment: 1. Download the  package :
https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.02-Windows-x86_64.exe
2. Check and uninstall if any older version is existing from App and Feature settings 
3. Verify the installation 
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/verify-install/
Note:
This should work fine i have reinstalled and verified it [this version works on Python 3.7]

Comment: Tried all of that. In fact I downloaded the 2019-10 file too and checked. Every time I tried it would still get stuck at different locations. Same seems to be the issue when I try to install Miniconda. I'm going to sit down today and complete the rest of the registry edits and then see how it goes further.